# Extra property does not refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, inotifypropertychanged

I have made a custom button, since I would like to be able to set to differents strings, independantly, for the content. I have then made a `ControlTemplate` in my xaml, to specify how the two contents should be rendered. The content is bound to sub-properties of a selected item (from a list view). I am using `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the view, if the selection changed. And then the content and sub-content of my button, should change accordingly.

Now this works fine for the content. But the sub-content only displays anything, when the program is first loaded. After the first change in selection, it goes blank, and stays blank.

Have I missed something? Is there anything else I need to add?

**Custom button C#**

```
public class DoubleContentButton : Button
{
    static  DoubleContentButton() { }

    public object SubContent
    {
        get => GetValue(SubContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(SubContentProperty, value);
    }

    public  static readonly DependencyProperty SubContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(name: "SubContent", typeof(object), typeof(DoubleContentButton), new UIPropertyMetadata());
}
```

**Custom button control template**

```
<Style x:Key="StatusButton" TargetType="{x:Type custom:DoubleContentButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type custom:DoubleContentButton}">
                <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 20">

                    <!-- This updates -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

                    <!--  This does not update -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding SubContent}" />

                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Implementation of button**

```
<custom:DoubleContentButton
    Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
    Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Status}"
    SubContent="{Binding SelectedItem.SubStatus}"
    Style="{StaticResource StatusButton}" />
```

Comment: Does it update if you set `SubContent="{Binding SelectedItem.Status}"`?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Your DoubleContentButton works fine for me.

Comment: @Rekshino no, nothing shows. The only way I can get it to display anything, is if I replace the `{TemplateBinding SubContent}` with a static text (e.g. "Hello world!").

Comment: I think it might have been a build error. After I deleted the Debug folder and re-build everything, it seems to work. Gotta love Visual Studio sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your SubStatus property has a PropertyChangedEventHandler raised on the setter of the "SubStatus" or if it has, is it properly raised?

Like this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

private void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
{  
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));  
} 

public string SubStatus
{
    get { ... }
    set
    {  
        _SubStatus = value;  
        OnPropertyRaised(nameof(SubStatus));
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is not necessary when only the SelectedItem property changes (which appears to be what OP is asking). That property should then of course fire a change notification.

Comment: There is a notification, when selected item changed. Both `Status` and `SubStatus` are read-only properties of `SelectedItem`, so there is no setters to modify. Also, as far as I know, that shouldn't be nessesary.